# Text color of link not appearing on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a link that looks like a button and it looks ok in IE and FF, but not on chrome.

Here is an example: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=228

It is the teal button in the middle of the page that says "follow problem"

I needed the text to appear white, but for some reason it isn't doing that.

Here is the css:

```
a:link.image_button 
{
  display: block;
  background: #4E9CAF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

and here is the HTML for the link:

```
<a class="image_button" id="follow_problem" rel="nofollow" href="#" style="display: none;" title="Update me via email whenever there are developments in this discussion.">Follow Problem</a>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me on Chrome. It just shows up as a teal button with white text.

Comment: Looks fine in chrome 15. Maybe the problem is with a:link {color: #3686A7;} ?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Maybe your style="display:none" is overriding, shouldn't be but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine for me on Chrome 15. I suggest you to create a new user account on your OS and try a fresh install of Chrome. Maybe one of your plugins is interfering.

Or right-click on link, inspect element, then go to "computed styles", and see where its color comes from.